# Null bytes in char* in QByteArray with QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt

I'm discovered that `char*` in `QByteArray` have null bytes. Code:

```
QByteArray arr;
QDataStream stream(&arr, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
stream << "hello";
```

Look at debugger variable view:

[image: char* in QByteArray]

I don't understand why I have three empty bytes at the beginning. I know that `[3]` byte is string length. Can I remove last byte? I know it's null-terminated string, but for my application I must have raw bytes (with one byte at beggining for store length).

More weird for me is when I use QString:

```
QString str = "hello";
[rest of code same as above]
stream << str;
```

[image: QString in QByteArray]

It's don't have null at end, so I think maybe null bytes before each char informs that next byte is char?

Just two questions:

1. Why so much null bytes?
2. How I can remove it, including last null byte?

Comment: QStrings are 16bit unicode strings - that's why you see 2 bytes per character in your second example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand why I have three empty bytes at the beginning.

It's a fixed-size, uint32_t (4-byte) header.  It's four bytes so that it can specify data lengths as long as (2^32-1) bytes.  If it was only a single byte, then it would only be able to describe strings up to 255 bytes long, because that's the largest integer value that can fit into a single byte.

> Can I remove last byte? I know it's null-terminated string, but for my
>   application I must have raw bytes (with one byte at beggining for
>   store length).

Sure, as long as the code that will later parse the data array is not depending on the presence of a trailing NUL byte to work correctly.

> More weird for me is when I use QString [...] it's don't have null at end, so I think maybe null bytes before each char informs that next byte is char?

Per the [Qt serialization documentation page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/datastreamformat.html), a QString is serialized as:

```
- If the string is null: 0xFFFFFFFF (quint32)
- Otherwise:  The string length in bytes (quint32) followed by the data in UTF-16.
```

If you don't like that format, instead of serializing the QString directly, you could do something like

```
stream << str.toUtf8();
```

instead, and that way the data in your QByteArray would be in a simpler format (UTF-8).

> Why so much null bytes?

They are used in fixed-size header fields when the length-values being encoded are small; or to indicate the end of NUL-terminated C strings.

> How I can remove it, including last null byte?

You could add the string in your preferred format (no NUL terminator but with a single length header-byte) like this:

```
const char * hello = "hello";
char slen = strlen(hello);
stream.writeRawData(&slen, 1);
stream.writeRawData(hello, slen);
```

... but if you have the choice, I highly recommend just keeping the NUL-terminator bytes at the end of the strings, for these reasons:

1. A single preceding length-byte will limit your strings to 255 bytes long (or less), which is an unnecessary restriction that will likely haunt you in the future.
2. Avoiding the NUL-terminator byte doesn't actually save any space, because you've added a string-length byte to compensate.
3. If the NUL-terminator byte is there, you can simply pass a pointer to the first byte of the string directly to any code expects a C-style string, and it will be able to use the string immediately (without any data-conversion steps).  If you rely on a different convention instead, you'll end up having to make a copy of the entire string before you can pass it to that code, just so that you can append a NUL byte to the end of the string so that that C-string-expecting code can use it.  That will be CPU-inefficient and error-prone.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, now I understand it. Also, writeRawData works correctly :) Sadly, I must remove NUL terminator, because data created this way will be send by TCP to server with specific, constant format.